# Mongodb how to find docs with more than 2 array items with specific value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find, aggregation-framework

can somebody tell me please how to find items in Mongodb array which contains more than 2 items with specific value? For example if I have two documents like this:

```
{
    someArray: [
        {'aaa' => 1},
        {'aaa' => 1}
    ]
}
{
    someArray: [
        {'aaa' => 1},
        {'aaa' => 2}
    ]
}
```

I need to find the first document which contains **two items which 'aaa' value is 1**. I dont mean $elemMatch I need to count the number of the matched items. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you show sample output

Comment: I dont understand. Output should be the document. For my purpose _id will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $gte: [
                    { $size: { $filter: { input: "$someArray", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.aaa", 1 ] } } } },
                    2
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```

[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) allows you to apply your condition, then you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get the length of filtered array and compare it againts your value using `$gte`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`$indexOfArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to find whether the array contains that element and then compare with the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the array using [**`$eq`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      { "$ne": [{ "$indexOfArray": ["$someArray.aaa", 1] }, -1] },
      { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$someArray" }, 2] }
    ]
  }
}).limit(1)
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Liwrhe-49R)

Comment: It's all about interpretation here, and what actually means "two items which 'aaa' value is 1", in this case any of them has to have `aaa` set to `1`, I'm not sure if that's the point

Comment: ***:-):-):-)*** Yes. Even I am confused now. I thought may be any of the element contains value `1`. But I think you are right both elements should contain the `1`. Let's see what OP needs. Most probably you are right.